# Getting unexpected interfaces in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, network-interface, interface

Suddenly getting some bulk interfaces which should not be in server. Interfaces named like as0t1,as0t2,as0t3 etc. Almost 40 interface like this has been created of which i have no idea. Actually some people had access to this server. May be some one has mistakenly created those. We have already restricted server access. Now need to remove those interfaces. Any suggestion?

N:B: Please be informed that in **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts** location i haven't found those interfaces except the physical ones.

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These interfaces are probably created by OpenVPN Access Server. You need to uninstall it to get rid of the interfaces.

Comment: PPTP protocol was there which was causing such problem. after removing that problem got solved. Btw thanks for your suggestion..